# Laravel add Commision to Balance for Referral System on Registration Process

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I work on an Laravel 5 Referral System and now i want give the referer user for every registrated Member, where use his URL ID some Money as  Commision where he get instantly after the other user sign up.

I have write an Code in my Registration process for affliate, but it dont add the Value to Balance

My AuthController:

```
    $user = new User;

         $user->username = $request->username;

         $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);

         $user->uniqueid = 'ID'.str_random(28);

         $user->balance = 0;

         $user->save();






                $referal_id = $user->id;



                $referer_id = $request['referal_id'];



                $referalUserData = [

                    'referer_id' => $referer_id,

                    'referal_id' => $referal_id,

                    'created_at' => Carbon::now()

                 ];



                $insert = ReferralUser::insert($referalUserData);






              if (session()->has('referal_id')) {

             $referal_id->user->balance += 0.01;
             $referal_id->user->save();

          }


session()->flash('user_id',$user->id);

     return redirect()->route('emailregister');


    }
```

This is the Code where i have write now to add Balance:

```
          if (session()->has('referal_id')) {

         $referal_id->user->balance += 0.01;
         $referal_id->user->save();

      }
```

Where 0.01$ is the Amount/Value that i want add to the Users Balance wheres the owner of URL and ID. (Not the Member where use the URL for Registation)

Anyone have an Idea why i dont get any error and its dont add Balance?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you setting the referrer Id in session?

Comment: Is session not the Sign up Process? or how can i write it on other way but only if referal_id is not null in URL?

Comment: No session wouldn't have anything to do with what you've got posted. Session does often times handle authentication if that's what you mean by sign up process. `$referal_id->user->balance += 0.01;` that is wrong too. $referal_id is an int not an object. You should be using to query for the user, not as a relationship.

Comment: Any Example please?

Comment: I don't know, am I going to see a part of the money from this referral system since this is like the 4th or 5th question I've answered about it so far?